# Concurrent login restriction does not work when applying session clustering with embedded Tomcat at spring security

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security

I applied Spring Security to my Spring application, and while modifying the code to fit the duplicated environment, I found out that concurrent login restriction does not work when doing session clustering through Tomcat. What additional settings do I need to configure?

spring boot version:2.7.10
spring security version: 5.7.7

// security config

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final MemberRepository memberRepository;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // path
        http.
                authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers().permitAll()               
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        ;

        // concurrent login restriction
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .expiredUrl("/error/expired")
                .and().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)

        ;


        http.logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        ;


        // login
        http
                .formLogin()

                .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {

                }) 
                .failureHandler((request, response, exception) -> {

                })
        ;

        // auth
        http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
                    
                }) 
                .accessDeniedHandler((request, response, accessDeniedException) -> { 

                }) 
        ;
        return http.build();


    }


    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }


    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


}
```

// Embedded Tomcat session clustering

```
@Configuration
public class TomcatClusterConfig implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {
    @Override
    public void customize(final TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addContextCustomizers(new TomcatClusterContextCustomizer());
    }
}
class TomcatClusterContextCustomizer implements TomcatContextCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(final Context context) {
        context.setDistributable(true); 

        DeltaManager manager = new DeltaManager();
        manager.setExpireSessionsOnShutdown(false);
        manager.setNotifyListenersOnReplication(true);
        context.setManager(manager);
        configureCluster((Engine) context.getParent().getParent());
    }
    private void configureCluster(Engine engine) {
        //cluster
        SimpleTcpCluster cluster = new SimpleTcpCluster();
        cluster.setChannelSendOptions(6);

        //channel
        GroupChannel channel = new GroupChannel();
        //membership setting
        McastService mcastService = new McastService();
        mcastService.setAddress("228.0.0.4");
        mcastService.setPort(45564); // TCP&UDP port 오픈 필요
        mcastService.setFrequency(500);
        mcastService.setDropTime(3000);
        channel.setMembershipService(mcastService);

        //receiver
        NioReceiver receiver = new NioReceiver();
        receiver.setAddress("auto");
        receiver.setMaxThreads(6);
        receiver.setPort(5000); // TCP port 오픈 필요
        channel.setChannelReceiver(receiver);

        //sender
        ReplicationTransmitter sender = new ReplicationTransmitter();
        sender.setTransport(new PooledParallelSender());
        channel.setChannelSender(sender);

        //interceptor
        channel.addInterceptor(new TcpPingInterceptor());
        channel.addInterceptor(new TcpFailureDetector());
        channel.addInterceptor(new MessageDispatchInterceptor());
        cluster.addValve(new ReplicationValve());
        cluster.addValve(new JvmRouteBinderValve());
        cluster.setChannel(channel);
        cluster.addClusterListener(new ClusterSessionListener());
        engine.setCluster(cluster);
    }
}
```

curious about what additional settings need to be configured.